# Android: How to implement com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView without using a map activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

I tried to implement `MapView` inside a linear layout and this layout is not belong to a `MapActivity`. Also I didn't use a `fragment` to implement that process.

Also I got an api key from Google Developer Console and enable some apis which are related to Locations and Maps.

This is my android manifest in android studio,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sec.asdf_solutions.biz.security">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RosterActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />        

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/api_key" />        

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my **layout** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_roster_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".RosterActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_roster">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/roster_map_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:apiKey="xxx--yyy-zzz-aaa-www"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/roster_map_view"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="#765491"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roster_ac_date_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#563e6b"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="5 th MAY 2017"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="START TIME"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="END TIME"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:id="@+id/roster_st_time_text"
                        android:text="08.30 AM"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:id="@+id/roster_ed_time_text"
                        android:text="05.30 PM"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/roster_location_text"
                    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_place_small"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:lines="3"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="Australian Strategic Partnership\n#9, School Lane, Kollpity, Colombo 3"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/roster_accept_btn"
                        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:background="@color/loginColor"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="ACCEPT" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/roster_reject_btn"
                        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:background="@color/acceptedPurpleColour"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="REJECT" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**buid.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sec.asdf_solutions.biz.security"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my activity for implement above process,

```
public class RosterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //protected MapView mMapView;

    android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton acceptButton;
    android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton rejectButton;
    private Context context;

    private String token;
    private long idLong;
    private Response responseBody;

    TextView rosterDateTextView;
    TextView rosterStartTimeTextView;
    TextView rosterEndTimeTextView;
    TextView rosterLocationTextView;

    View mainView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_roster);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_roster);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Special Note** : I am not using MapActivity.

Have any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [MapView's documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView):

> Users of this class must forward all the life cycle methods from the Activity or Fragment containing this view to the corresponding ones in this class. In particular, you must forward on the following methods:
>
> - onCreate(Bundle)
> - onStart()
> - onResume()
> - onPause()
> - onStop()
> - onDestroy()
> - onSaveInstanceState()
> - onLowMemory()

All that `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment` does is forward all of those callbacks to the `MapView` so if you do that work yourself, there is no need to have a specific superclass.

For example:

```
MapView rosterMapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_roster);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_roster);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    rosterMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.roster_map_view);
    rosterMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {{
    super.onPause();
    rosterMapView.onPause();
}
```

Etc, etc - override each method and pass the call onto your `MapView`.

Comment: Can you provide me a code snippet for above method implementation ? If you can it is a great help to me

Comment: You just override each callback and pass the call through to MapView, just like it says. I added an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for a correct answer. Please give me a mark if you can

Comment: Correct answer, I was struggling for a long time. After implementing the callbacks, I felt that mapView response was very slow, gestures etc so went back to fragment which seem to be very efficient and smooth

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way.Also you should never post/show your API key. Try to hide.

```
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

                <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
     </Linear Layout>


    //finding xml view from xml layout
           GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I forget to hide it